# Ubuntu Server 9.10 Karmic Koala and Squid Proxy server installation errors

Tags: ubuntu, squid, ubuntu-9.10

This is what I get. Could someone please point me as to how to fix this?

```
root@thinkcode:~# apt-get install squid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  squid-common squid-langpack
Suggested packages:
  squidclient squid-cgi logcheck-database resolvconf smbclient winbind
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  squid squid-common squid-langpack
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,346kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,651kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  squid-langpack squid-common squid
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main squid-langpack 3.HEAD.20090706-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main squid-common 2.7.STABLE6-2ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main squid-common 2.7.STABLE6-2ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main squid 2.7.STABLE6-2ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/squid-langpack/squid-langpack_3.HEAD.20090706-1ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/squid/squid-common_2.7.STABLE6-2ubuntu2.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/squid/squid_2.7.STABLE6-2ubuntu2.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Followed Shane's suggestion and this is what I get:

```
root@thinkcode:~# sudo aptitude install squid squid-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
Writing extended state information... Done
The following packages are BROKEN:
  squid-common 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  squid 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 84 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,116kB of archives. After unpacking 2,548kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  squid-common: Depends: squid-langpack which is a virtual package.
Unable to resolve dependencies!  Giving up...
The following packages are BROKEN:
  squid-common 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  squid 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 84 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,116kB of archives. After unpacking 2,548kB will be used.
aptitude failed to find a solution to these dependencies.  You can solve them yourself by hand or type 'n' to quit.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  squid-common: Depends: squid-langpack which is a virtual package.
Resolve these dependencies by hand? [N/+/-/_/:/?] N
Abort.
```

These are my repos in (/etc/apt/sources.list):

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 9.10 _Karmic Koala_ - Release i386 (20091027.2)]/ karmic main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 9.10 _Karmic Koala_ - Release i386 (20091027.2)]/ karmic main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

#>deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
#>deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
#>deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted
#>deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu karmic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu karmic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 9.10 is long since out of support, and the repositories have been discontinued; thus the 404s you're seeing.

You'll need to change your repositories to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` - once that's done, I'd recommend an upgrade to 10.04 (run `do-release-upgrade`) to get on a supported version.  See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) for details.

Comment: Thanks Shane. I did change the repos, and I updated with the error I now get.

Comment: Did you do an `apt-get update` after making the changes to the sources file?

Comment: All the security related domains (http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/restricted Packages) are giving a 404. May I have the old-URL for security.ubuntu.com?

Comment: apt-get update did the trick, thank you so much!

Comment: @ThinkCode Same deal for security and the other (universe, multiverse) repositories that you still have pointed to the main archive server - all are on the same old-releases server.  `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe`, `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse`, `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-security main restricted`.  And again, I'd really recommend an upgrade - those archives haven't had a security update in over half a year.